# Trying to display the pilots with zero Flight Miles

Tags: sql, sql-server

the following query does what I want MOSTLY

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(TP.intPilotID, ' ', TP.strFirstName, ' ', TP.strLastName, ', ', SUM(TF.intMilesFlown)) AS MILES
                        FROM TFlights AS TF
                        JOIN TPilotFlights as TPF
                        ON TF.intFlightID=TPF.intFlightID
                        JOIN TPilots AS TP
                        ON TPF.intPilotID = TP.intPilotID
                        GROUP BY TP.intPilotID, TP.strFirstName, TP.strLastName
```

how can I get it to show the one guy who hasn't flown yet (and display his miles as zero)

I have tried rearranging the order of the joins which only messed up the mileage totals

Comment: either use a left outer join  or do a union all on pilots that have no flights

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question lacks some important parts that would help us answer it. I see that you received an answer already. If that answer is correct, act accordingly (upvote and accept it). If it isn't, comment on it to clarify what is wrong with it. For your future questions (and if answer you received didn't help you) try editing this question according to information you received in 2 links I provided.

Comment: Also, do [tag your RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned can be accomplished with a left outer join or a union all on pilots that do not have flights here is the union all scenario

```
   SELECT 
      DISTINCT CONCAT(
        TP.intPilotID, 
        ' ', 
        TP.strFirstName, 
        ' ', 
        TP.strLastName, 
        ', ' as name, 
        SUM(TF.intMilesFlown)
      ) AS MILES 
    FROM 
      TFlights AS TF 
      JOIN TPilotFlights as TPF ON TF.intFlightID = TPF.intFlightID 
      JOIN TPilots AS TP ON TPF.intPilotID = TP.intPilotID 
    GROUP BY 
      TP.intPilotID, 
      TP.strFirstName, 
      TP.strLastName 
    union all 
    select 
      CONCAT(
        TP.intPilotID, 
        ' ', 
        TP.strFirstName, 
        ' ', 
        TP.strLastName, 
        ', ' as name, 
        0 as miles 
        from 
          TPilots AS TP 
        where 
          not exists (
            select 
              1 
            from 
              TPilotFlights as TPF 
            where 
              TPF.intPilotID = TP.intPilotID
          )
```

Comment: thank you! I did more searching after posting the question and found the left outer join part but was still drawing a blank as to the zero part

Comment: so for the left outer join where the mileage is null you would just use coalesce to change null to 0